# tokio::sync::broadcast::Receiver<T> is not Clone

Tags: rust, channel, rust-tokio

I have a struct like this:

```rust
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Foo {
    ...  // other state
    receiver: tokio::sync::watch::Receiver<T>,
}
```

But I realize for purposes of the application I actually need a `tokio::sync::broadcast` channel, which itself only implements `Clone` in the `Sender` half, not the `Receiver`. So I can't simply make a drop-in replacement for the receiver as `Clone` can't be derived. Maybe a manual `Clone` implementation is the answer, but I'm not sure what that would look like. It requires a handle to the sender and a call to `sender.subscriber()` I believe. Not sure this is the right approach.

How can I have a type `Foo` which I can clone handles to where each one is capable of awaiting to receive a new message, if the channel type changes to broadcast?

Comment: What is `T` ? it needs to be Cloneable to clone `Receiver`

Comment: The type `T` is `Option<U>` where `U: Clone`. For some reason this isn't letting me derive `Clone` on the containing `Foo` struct. Edit: I don't see anywhere `Receiver<T>: Clone`, are you sure about this?

Comment: Strange, since `T` was ambiguous, intuitively I also thought that receiver should be `Clone`able but looks like it hasn't implemented in that way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Receivers in `tokio::sync::broadcast` are created by calling [subscribe](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.30.0/tokio/sync/broadcast/struct.Sender.html#method.subscribe) method on `Sender` as the [module documentation](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.30.0/tokio/sync/broadcast/index.html) says:

> New `Receiver` handles are created by calling `Sender::subscribe`. The returned `Receiver` will receive values sent after the call to `subscribe`.

However you can also create new `Receiver` by calling [resubscribe](https://docs.rs/tokio/1.30.0/tokio/sync/broadcast/struct.Receiver.html#method.resubscribe) on it. Which will:

> Re-subscribes to the channel starting from the current tail element.
>
> This Receiver handle will receive a clone of all values sent after it has resubscribed. This will not include elements that are in the queue of the current receiver.

And this method is of course only available for `T: Clone`.

So if you want your `Foo` to be `Clone` (and you are willing to accept limitations mentioned in the `Receiver` documentation), you have to implement it manually:

```rust
struct Foo<T> {
    ...  // other state
    receiver: tokio::sync::watch::Receiver<T>,
}

impl<T: Clone> Clone for Foo {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        Self {
            ... // clone other state
            receiver: self.receiver.resubscribe(),
        }
    }
}
```